# windows animation in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm asking how to use the windows frame animations in my custom JFrame, to be more specific I'm talking about the animation that happens when you minimize or maximize the windows frame and that effect that appear when you put the top of your Window in one of the corners and it auto resize.

Answer (score 3):

Those animations are OS specific, as such the only (real way) to access them is via JNI

Comment: @Alysson: if you do a decent search of the MSDN resource you will likely see which DLL you need to work with.